# Matplotlib graph with "event" dots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with bid and ask prices of a stock over time. I can plot both lines, but I would like to add the transactions in the graph as well. But I don't know how to do that : only a dotted line with last transaction level but that makes not much sense.

This is my df:

```
      now        bid     ask    last    lasttime    lastsize
224 17:19:46    138.00  138.34  138.0   18:00:46    26950
225 17:19:57    138.00  138.34  138.0   18:00:46    26950
226 17:20:09    138.00  138.34  138.0   18:00:46    26950
227 17:20:20    138.00  138.34  138.0   18:00:46    26950
228 17:20:32    138.00  138.34  138.0   18:00:46    26950
229 17:20:43    137.91  138.34  137.9   18:20:33    56950
230 17:20:54    137.91  138.34  137.9   18:20:33    56950
231 17:21:06    137.91  138.34  137.9   18:20:33    56950
232 17:21:17    137.90  138.33  137.9   18:20:33    56950
233 17:21:29    137.90  138.33  137.9   18:20:33    56950
234 17:21:40    137.81  138.32  137.9   18:21:31    233050
235 17:21:51    137.81  138.32  137.9   18:21:31    233050
236 17:22:03    137.81  138.32  137.9   18:21:31    233050
```

And with this code I can get the graph:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 10))
ax.plot(df2.now, df2['last'], color = "blue", label="last", linestyle="dotted")
ax.plot(df2.now, df2['bid'], color = "green", label="bid", linewidth=3)
ax.plot(df2.now, df2['ask'], color = "red", label="ask")
plt.legend()
```

But ideally I would like to see the transactions as dots, with bigger transactions representing a bigger dot (and size is the "lastsize"). In this df there are 2 transactions.

Now I get the graph below, which is of limited use.

[image: graph]

Comment: `np.diff(df2["last"])` should give you a nice idea of how "big" the transactions are. Then you can scale or normalize this array to use it as the size of your dots.

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for